# Upload in chrome background tab

Tags: google-chrome, background-process, evaporate.js

I am using [evaporate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evaporate) to upload stuff to s3, and there's a lot of files to be uploaded. I really want this process to be seamless to the user. There's one problem though. Google Chrome has [Throttle expensive background timers feature](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6172836527865856) that drastically decreases the performance of the process.

I had a few ideas on how to handle this issue:

- Ask the user to disable throttling for the tab. But I haven't found a way to do that for a specific tab and in some kind of [Mobile permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) style. All you can do as a developer is show user a guide on how to do that by going to `chrome://flags/#expensive-background-timer-throttling` page and manually change the flag.
- Playing a video/audio on the page is turning the throttling off according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs). Seems hacky though :-\

I'd be glad to hear any advice on how to resolve this situation. Maybe somebody already faced the same problem and have some experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Workers solve the issue. You need to put all the code inside though. So, if you trigger heavy computation outside of the web worker - those triggerings WILL be throttled. If you trigger computations outside of the web worker - everything works fine.